# How to turn off Facebook notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Recently I have developed a Facebook Application to post photos. Each time it posts photos I get a notification which is quite annoying. Is there any way to stop this notification. I have read the documentation and nothing is mentioned for it. There is an option in Facebook to close a type of  notification and such notifications don't show up in future. But there is no close icon for the notifications from my app. Is there any parameters or option that I have to change while creating the app. I want to turn off notification for my Application.

Please help

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct permissions? If you don't have permission from your users to create photos directly, they'll need to approve each photo you upload

Comment: I am just getting a notification and I don't want to approve it. Photos are already posted in the profile. This is a personal app only I am using it

Comment: Obviously you can't do this!